# How can I use @ContentChildren and only render a specific child component instead of all the children?

Tags: angular

I'm attempting to create a generic slideshow component which will take multiple components, and then it will loop through based on certain user actions.
It's very similar to the Angular Material's [stepper component](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview).

So far, I've figured out that you can use `@ContentChildren` to get references to multiple (passed in) components/content, but I'm not sure how to actually render the components.

Here's an example I created: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yjfbwb
The app.component.html file contains a `<tours></tours>` tag which you can pass in anything you want as long as you tag it with `#tour`. And inside the tours.component.ts, you'll see that I'm just looping through the passed in components.
But how do I actually render them?

I've googled around, and it seems like it's not possible the way I'm doing it? But perhaps I'm not searching properly. Ideally, I would like to make this tours component as simple to use as possible (basically how it is in the example above) for my team.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can of course set them to display none or something, but that will always instantiate all components, you cannot prevent that this way. But I think what you really want to do is pass an array of items via Input and then a nested template to which you get a reference and render it for the corresponding items.

Comment: Also, Angular Material is open source so you can always just go check out its source ;-)

Comment: Have you seen this: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to achive this.

Here is a simple solution. Just to get the idea. You may want to do it differently according to your exact problem.

For every element you like to project in your tours component you have to create a Template. You can do this via a `StructuralDirective`.

```js
import {Directive, TemplateRef, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appTour]'
})
export class TourDirective {
  @Input('appTour') id: number;
  constructor(public template: TemplateRef<any>) {
  }

}
```

Mark the elements inside your `ToursComponent` with the directive (Don't forget the asterisk):

```html
<tours>
  <p *appTour="123">hello</p>
  <p *appTour="1234">world</p>
</tours>
```

To identify the directives you can pass for example the `id` of the tour to your template.

Now inside your `ToursComponent` inject the `TourDirective` via `@ContentChildren` and pass the template you like to render inside a `ViewContainerRef | <ng-container>`

```js
import { Component, ContentChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';
import { TourDirective } from './tour.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'tours',
  template: `
  <ng-container *ngFor="let tour of tours.toArray()">
    <ng-container *ngIf="tour.id === tourToDisplay">
      <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="tour.template"></ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>`,
})
export class ToursComponent {

  public tourToDisplay = 123;
  
  @ContentChildren(TourDirective) tours: QueryList<TourDirective>;
}
```

[Updated Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-acex9z?file=src/app/tours.component.ts)